# How do I tackle ordered text widget on multiple pages in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, module, widget

Hey guys. so I'm not quite sure how to tackle my next big problem in this project.

I want to create an admin interface which allows my client to create a dynamic menu page for the food and drinks. Basically, I want him to be able to enter a short paragraph for the top of the page, and then 2-6 widgets that he can drag and drop onto the page. This menu will then render under owlhouse.com.au/food. I figure it'll be something to do with associations, but I have no idea how to construct a function which attaches dynamic data to the page on the fly.. and keep it in the layout the client wants (2 columns, diff modules for beer, wine, etc.)

HOW ON EARTH DO I GO ABOUT THIS?

thankyou,

~Harley

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic Data**

Build a "CRUD" interface that the client can log into. (Think blog entries). Store the content in the database (of course). Then provide a [drag & drop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) interface that allows the client to order them, assign them to pages, or whatever is needed to meet the requirement. When the client clicks update, you simply add/remove IDs to the content for the given page. When the page loads (like a blog page) it loads the content for the given IDs.

**Widgets**

The same would apply for widgets. I would build an element that provides the basic layout for the widget. Then build it the same way as the content. The client will have CRUD functionality with drag & drop interface to show which widgets are displayed.

Send me a PM if you need to hire someone. ;)

Comment: thanks for getting back to me! if I can weasle out a little more free advice, I have a couple of questions. Would the process be to include an element or modal box of add_widget on the menu page, which once added ajax saves and adds it to a drag bay below. Then in can be dragged from there to the drop/sortable zone, where ajax will attach the widget to the menu drop zone and increase $position by one and set the database field 'position' to the new value? sortable can then handle changing position, which I would have to attach on the fly. thanks :)